# How to highlight the clicked item from JS fetch()

Tags: javascript

This loads options from a json file with `fetch()`, when I click on one of the options it should highlight (color red), but all others should be black.

It only works with the first option, why the others don't change to black when other item is clicked?

https://jsfiddle.net/03gphxdt/

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')

fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5').then(response => {
  return response.json()
}).then(data => {
  div.innerHTML = `
        ${data.results[0].incorrect_answers.map(incorrect_answer => `<p class="answer">${incorrect_answer}</p>`).join("")}
     `
  div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('answer')) {
      // all items to be black (remove selected/red class )
      this.querySelector('.answer').classList.remove('selected')
      // add the selected/red class to only the item clicked
      event.target.classList.add('selected')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.answer {
  color: black;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click', function(event) { // clicking the div
  this.querySelectorAll('.answer').forEach(item => item.classList.remove('selected')); // remove all selected
  if (event.target.classList.contains('answer')) {
    // add on the clicked answer only
    event.target.classList.add('selected')
  }
})

fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5').then(response => {
  return response.json()
}).then(data => {
  div.innerHTML = `${data.results[0].incorrect_answers.map(incorrect_answer => `<p class="answer">${incorrect_answer}</p>`).join("")}`

})
```

```css
.answer {
  color: black;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: yeah, that's it! thanks I'll check your code and see what I got it wrong..

Comment: you did not loop over all the items when clicking one, to remove the other's class

Comment: `querySelector()` takes just the first one, didn't know that.

Comment: @baDrosa82 For completeness, `querySelector` returns the first match, while `querySelectorAll` returns an Array-like iterable (but not an actual array) of all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')

fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5').then(response => {
  return response.json()
}).then(data => {
  div.innerHTML = `
        ${data.results[0].incorrect_answers.map(incorrect_answer => `<p class="answer">${incorrect_answer}</p>`).join("")}
     `
  div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  
  for (let sibling of event.target.parentNode.children) {
    sibling.classList.remove('selected');
   }
   event.target.classList.add('selected')


  })
})
```

```css
.answer {
  color: black;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```